# XCode iPhone database information stream by using an external *.php file

Tags: php, iphone, database, xcode, stream

---My Xcode-ViewController.h is the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UILabel *Anzeige;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollAnzeige;
}

-(IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

---My Xcode-ViewController.m is the following (the things that i created/edited):

```
-(IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender{

    NSString *hostSTR = @"http://localhost/iphoneconnect.php";

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostSTR]];

    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *finalString = @"";

    finalString = [serverOutput  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"\n"];

    Anzeige.text = finalString;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [scrollAnzeige setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollAnzeige setContentSize:CGSizeMake(614, 730)];//614 breit


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

---My PHP-Code is the following:

```
<?

session_start();

$connect = mysql_connect("my.server.com", "user" , "pass") 
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden"); 

mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden"); 

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
        echo $x['coloumn1']." ".$x['coloumn2']." ".$x['coloumn3']." ".$x['coloumn4']." ".$x['coloumn5']." ".$x['coloumn6']." ".$x['coloumn7']." ".$x['coloumn8']." ".$x['coloumn9']." ".$x['coloumn10']." ".$x['coloumn11']." ".$x['coloumn12']."#";
}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Everything of this is working - downloading and showing the information from the database.
The most important thing i want to realize is, that the information is refreshing every second (or a higher delay - depends on what is possible).

I used usleep(1000), but the button in my simulator was like permanently pushed then and no information was showed at all.

After that, i tried to use a higher delay like 5 seconds, but the same problem appeared.
-> The button looked like permanently pushed and no information was showed at all.

How i can solve this problem - how can i make it working like a stream?

Greetz Shaddy

Answer (score 0):

usleep is blocking and stalls the execution of the code for the interval.

To refresh the data once a second, instantiate an `NSTimer` with the method `+timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` and add it to the main run loop.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
              target:self
              selector:@selector(refreshData:)
              userInfo:nil
              repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:@"NSDefaultRunLoopMode"];
```

Then move the request code to the method `refreshData:(NSTimer*)timer`. To stop the timer, you have to invoke `[timer invalidate]`.

Therefore, provided your above code works, the following should have the desired effect:

```
-(void)refreshData:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSString *hostSTR = @"http://localhost/iphoneconnect.php";

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostSTR]];

    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *finalString = @"";

    finalString = [serverOutput  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"\n"];

    Anzeige.text = finalString;

}


-(IBAction)StartButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (!timer){
        timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(refreshData:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:@"NSDefaultRunLoopMode"];
        [button setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        [button setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add `NSTimer *timer;` to your interface.

Best, Peter

Comment: At first i want to thank you for the fast & competently answer!
I tried it, but i failed. I will explain it..

Right now i declared "NSTimer *timer;" in the ViewController.h under
interface ViewController:UIViewController, but there i cant instantiate it.

And where is the main run loop?
I tried different ways to add your code in my one.
I'm new to all this stuff, so please excuse this.

Comment: Okay. You should get accustomed to using the reference manuals which are online. Google typically points to the manuals in its first hit if you enter sth. like NSRunLoop or NSTimer. If you still cant figure out, I can provide further code samples later on. Peter

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working. :-) I will practice a little with it now. It's already wednesday, but have a nice week :-)